# How to expose non Drupal tables in Views?

Tags: 7, views, database

I wonder what is the best way to allow the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to access external tables not in Drupal?

I tried the [Data](http://drupal.org/project/data) module, but it doesn't allow for a datetime datatype.

Comment: I have found this really good article: http://mydons.com/how-to-expose-custom-module-table-to-views-in-drupal/ 

I am going to try it out tonight and post later.

Comment: this comment could be of help, too : http://drupal.org/node/928802#comment-3614158

Answer (score 3):

The data module is a good start.

You can skip the data module and create your own views type with [hook_views_data()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7)
Angie has an example [here](http://drupal.org/node/610128#comment-2174272).

Date times can be tricky, if you post another question with your specific problem with date times there may be a solution.

You don't specify if the DB is the same. You would need to define a second database in your settings.php if you need to connect to a different DB.

Comment: Similarly there was a session on views at DrupalCon Denver http://denver2012.drupal.org/program/sessions/views-developers-architectural-overview where Bevan Rudge talks more about hook_views_data().