# Make node/field text input format available to Views

Tags: 7, views, input-formats

The standard *Content* list in Drupal 7 (displayed with the *Find content* menu item) gives me a table of nodes in the system with various attributes, such as the type. I want to add the *text* type (e.g. *Filtered HTML*).

How can I do this? Installing the *[Administration views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views)* module has made the table much more configurable, but there seems to be no way to include data from the `field_data_body` database table, which contains the information. The *[Table Wizard](http://drupal.org/project/tw)* and *[Data](http://drupal.org/project/data)* modules apparently provide this functionality, but are not done for Drupal 7.

Is there a way to do this without coding?

If I have to code it, do you recommend creating a new module (with which I have no experience) or patching up an existing one until it works well enough, and if so, which one?

PS: this can be regarded as a special case of a (frequently asked) [related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29321/drupal-7-exposing-non-drupal-tables-in-views).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do this with Views 3 in Drupal 7:

1. Add the field you need the format of to the view (E.g. field_body)
2. In the configuration form for that field tick the 'Rewrite the output of this field' box
3. Put the '[*field_name*-format]' token into the box

It will render the raw name of the input format, instead of the value.

Comment: I can add the field in question to the filter criteria for the view (it's called: *Content: Body (body:format)*) but I cannot add the same field to the list of fields to be displayed. Why not?

Comment: How do I determine the *field_name*?

Comment: It works! Turns out I had to add the name `[body-format]`. Still don't know how I could have determined this other than by reading the code or guessing.

Comment: how exactly do you add [body-format]
could you please say it clearly regards.
ASDA

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot and apparently I also forgot to document it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the third step when you want to achieve this in Drupal 8:
3. Put the '{{ body__format }}' token into the box.

This is because the token format changed between Drupal 7 & 8.